# 'random' : identifier not found error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, random

I'm trying to port a code that was written for UNIX to Visual studio and I'm getting the following errors

```
\random.cpp(29): error C3861: 'initstate': identifier not found
\random.cpp(37): error C3861: 'random': identifier not found
\random.cpp(49): error C3861: 'random': identifier not found
\random.cpp(51): error C3861: 'random': identifier not found
\random.cpp(63): error C3861: 'random': identifier not found
\random.cpp(78): error C3861: 'SQRT': identifier not found
\random.cpp(78): error C3861: 'LOG': identifier not found
\random.cpp(78): error C3861: 'COS': identifier not found
\random.cpp(87): error C3861: 'ABS': identifier not found
```

The code is long but the I already **included math.h** but I'm still getting these errors. It could be that those functions are UNIX-only! If so, what are my options to go about it?

Here's a modified sample of my code (the lines that are giving me errors);

```
if( NULL == initstate(2, rngState, 256) )
    do something...

int r = (int)( (rangeEnd - rangeStart) * random() );

double z = SQRT(-2.0 * LOG(x1)) * COS(2.0 * M_PI * x2);
```

Comment: Oh, I mean don't write the function names in ALL CAPS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SQRT` -> `sqrt`

`LOG` -> `log`

`COS` -> `cos`

`random` -> `rand` (Don't forget to `# include <stdlib.h>` for that)

And write the `initstate` before main or make a forward declaration.

Comment: How do I write `initstate` before main or make a forward declaration?
`initstate` is called in a different function (which is called my main)

Comment: For a forward declaration, put the function signature at the beginning of the code.

Comment: Sorry if this sounded trivial. But i don't have the definition of `initstate`. Shouldn't it be like `random`?

Comment: Then how are you calling `initstate`?

Comment: This is a code that was written for a UNIX system. I thought `initstate` is a predefined function just like `rand()`. It might be a UNIX-only function? How would I know. Thanks

Comment: Predefined? In which library? I mean, which libraries are included in your code?

Comment: The libraries included in the code are the following; `#include <stdio.h>, #include <stdlib.h>, #include <math.h>, #include <time.h>, #include <string.h>`

Comment: See whether the `stdlib.h` library contains those functions.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I just found this function in <stdlib.h> (from http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/stdlib.h.html). How-come it's giving an identifier not found error. Any suggestion what I can do about it?

Comment: Use the functions `srand()` and `rand()` from `stdlib.h` for the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Include stdlib.h and use function rand().

Also the functions has names in lowercase cos, log, sqrt.